# Wireless Network Slower than expected

Tags: wireless-networking, performance, nas

I have a Belkin N600 dual band router. On the network typically are my PC, 2 iPhones & 2 PS3's. At times there can be another PC and a couple of laptops.

I have configured the router so that the 2.4GHz band is B, G or N and the 5GHz band is N only. I also have a WD ShareSpace 4TB NAS wired directly into the router LAN port.

My PC has a Belkin N USB adaptor.

What I find when transferring files from my PC to the NAS box is that transfer speeds don't get above 2MB/s and typically are between 750KB/s and 950KB/s. On the task manager, link speed varies between 76MB/s and 20MB/s. Signal strength is usually very good or excellent.
I understand that I am never going to get 300MB/s out of this and to be honest I'd be happy with 20MB/s but 2MB/s is somewhat disappointing.

I have even gone to the lengths of removing all other items conected to the network except my PC. Even after a full reset of router and restart of PC just in case, the speed is still only 1MB/s.

Any ideas?

Comment: So how can I resolve this and when I have how do I allocate bandwidth to specific devices so that my PC gets a bigger slice.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're confusing [MebiBytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte)/s (1,048,576's of 8-bit bytes) with megabits/s (1,000,000's of single bits). Local disk and file I/O is usually measured in MebiBytes/s, whereas network link speeds are usually measured in megabits/s.

Talking about remote fileserver performance requires caution because it's file I/O that rides on top of network I/O, so filesystem engineers (and file copy performance tools) want to talk about it in MebiBytes/s and network engineers (and network performance tools) want to talk about it in megabits/s.

Your Belkin N600 is capable of up to 300 megabits/s signaling, but you beware that Wi-Fi has a lot of overhead, so the rule of thumb is that your TCP throughput on Wi-Fi is usually about half your signaling rate. So 150 megabits/s, which is roughly 18 MebiBytes/s. But that's in idea RF conditions, with ideal TCP usage. Once you add the overhead of a remote filesystem protocol like SMB and whatever app you're using to do the copies, I think I'd be happy with 15 MebiBytes/s.

Then there's the question of how much throughput your WD ShareSpace 4TB NAS is capable of. According [this review at SmallNetBuilder](http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/nas/nas-reviews/30586-western-digital-sharespace-reviewed?showall=&start=3), that box is pretty slow and can only get about 20 MebiByte/s sustained throughput even on gigabit Ethernet. If that slowness is due to latency issues, then it'll have a big impact on what kind of throughput you can get from it even over wireless.

When you say "On the task manager, link speed varies between 76MB/s and 20MB/s", is that in reference to the network interface link speed or the file copy speed? And are you sure it's in MebiBytes/s or could it be in megabits/s? I would expect megabits/s since it's a network link.

If your Wi-Fi signaling rate is only 20 megabits/s at times, then your ideal TCP app throughput would be about 2.4 MebiBytes/s, further degraded by the WD ShareSpace NAS's latency and SMB and app copy overhead, and your 750 KibiByte/s throughput starts to make sense.

If I were you, there'd be two main things I'd be doing to speed this up:

1. Improve my Wi-Fi signaling rate to the 300 megabits/s the Belkin gear should be capable of. This might mean moving the PC closer to the AP, making sure wide (40MHz wide, HT40) channels are in use, making sure I selected nice clean channels in both 2.4GHz and 5GHz, and making sure my PC is joining on the less-likely-to-be-congested 5GHz band.
2. Improve my fileserver latency by getting a faster device to act as a fileserver.

Comment: You are correct about Megabits and bytes, I did means bits but was a little careless with the capitols. I am begining to realize that the choice of NAS box was a little hasty but I'm stuck with it for now. I think the simlest was to get the transfer rates to an acceptable level may be to go for a LAN cable between the router and my PC. Mine is the only one that will be doing the heavy transfers the other gear will be mainly accessing those files and a couple of seconds delay while an image loads is not the end of the world.